# React toolkit Query- How to use multiple query in same function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

Greeting, I'm stuck in using RTK query to fetch multiple data in one function component.  Please help if you know the way out.  Thanks a lot.

**My objective**
I want to fetch two api with RTK query, both using "GET" method, the base url is the same, the only difference is the query string.

**My problem**
I cannot change my query string if I only set one query in my function component because it will change the data I rendered from fetched data.

Since the new set of data provide information for the original data.  I cannot spilt the component into two.

**What I've tried**
I tried to set another query below my original query in my RTK code like this.

```
export const createIssueApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "createLabelApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://api.github.com/repos",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["issues"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({

...... original query above, new query I set below
getClosedIssues: builder.query<GetLebal[], Parameter>({
      query: ({ type, name, repo, query }) => ({
        url: `/${name}/${repo}/${type}${query}`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `token ${process.env.REACT_APP_PASSWORD}`,
        }),
      }),
      providesTags: ["issues"],
    }),
  }),
});
```

Then I tried to fetch 2 api using this query in same component like this

```
 const { data } = useGetAllIssuesQuery({
    type: "issues",
    name: "some-name",
    repo: "some-issue",
    query: `query-1`,
  });
//I cannot change query-1 dynamically or else the data I rendered below will also be changed.

  const { data } = useGetClosedIssuesQuery({
    type: "issues",
    name: "some-name",
    repo: "some-issue",
    query: `query-2`,
  });
```

The problem I encountered is, I obviously cannot redeclare data again, but it seems like RTK query only allow me to destructure the api result by `const{data}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the query hooks return the fetched data in a `data` property in the hook return value. This doesn't mean you need to keep it named `data`. When using destructuring assignment you can also rename properties that you are destructuring.

Example:

```
const { data: allIssues } = useGetAllIssuesQuery(....);
const { data: closedIssues } = useGetClosedIssuesQuery(....);
```